# Performance Benefit/Cost of using DATE instead of DATETIME for Database-First LINQ to Entities with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I have an SQL Database with a Table that contains 571684 records,
In each of these records is a DateTime called "Date", worse than that name is the Time aspect of the date time isn't used at all.

I investigated the SQL DB size for DATE and DATETIME and found Date to be much smaller than DATETIME.
(3 Bytes Vs 8 Bytes)

I would go ahead and make the obvious optimisation but I'm concerned about how LINQ to Entities will handle the SQL DATE type considering Entity only had DateTime.

Does the inner SQL generated by LINQ have to convert the DATE to DATETIME for Entity? is there a benefit to updating the field to DATE or will this hurt my query execution time because of Entity Framework?

Thanks.

Comment: Saving 5 bytes per record is not an optimization I'd make - it doesn't matter at all in the big picture.

Comment: I've read before now that DATETIME2(3) would be the same precision as DATETIME but at 7Bs instead of 8Bs, however, I know for a fact that the time component in this circumstance will never be relevant so neither of them are as small as DATE despite being just as useful for storage.

Do you have information regarding the query execution time?

I'll edit my first question to be specific, I was referring to the Inner SQL that the LINQ generates; would the SQL contain any conversion from DATE to DATETIME that could slow down query execution?

Any citation or specs appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in Entity Framework's [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx), `Date` (Sql Server) is mapped to `DateTime` (.Net).

This is a direct conversion. EF doesn't generate SQL that first converts to `DateTime`. Why should it? The .Net data type is oversized for the Sql Server data type.

I wouldn't worry about performance or storage too much. The only thing that would justify a conversion, in my view, is semantics. A `Date` data type *conveys* that the time component doesn't matter, it helps making the column self-explanatory.